# Getting [object Object] instead of object in React

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm fetching an array of objects in my React application. Later I am returning a `Product` component to each object.

```
 const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/products")
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(resp => {
        console.log(resp); //line 55
        setProducts(resp)
      })
  }, []);

  return (
      <div>
        {products.map(product => {
          return <Product product={product} />
        })}
      </div>
  );
```

This is result of my `console.log(resp)` in line 55:

```
    Array(6) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object { id: 1, name: "prod 3", amount: 30, … }
​​
active: true
​​
amount: 30
​​
id: 1
​​
name: "prod 3"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
1: Object { id: 23, name: "prod 2", amount: 20, … }
​
2: Object { id: 4, name: "Angular course", amount: 19, … }
​
3: Object { id: 42, name: "peanut butter", amount: 13, … }
​
4: Object { id: 43, name: "soup", amount: 12, … }
​
5: Object { id: 15, name: "hot-dog", amount: 11, … }
​

​
length: 6
​
<prototype>: Array []
```

So I am passing a single object to my `Product` component. However, when I want to view the passed object in the logs, I get the object inside the object:

```
 const Product = (product) => {
      console.log(product); // result: Object { product: {…} }
 }
```

Why am I getting an object inside an object instead of a single object?

Comment: Because components take a props object as their parameter. You may have meant `({ product })` to destructure it, or meant to use props, e.g., `(props)` and access it via `props.product`.

Comment: props are wrapped in an object and then pass to child component. So you can destructure as `const Product = ({product}) => {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In react the argument for a component is always their `props` object. This is an object with all the properties you define in the tag. So, for example if you define `<Product anotherProp={anotherProp} product={product} />` you would get a `props` object with the keys `product` and `anotherProp`.
So the correct way to get the `product` is through destructuring assingment.

```
const Product = (props) => {
      const {product} = props;
      console.log(product); // result: Object { product: {…} }
 }
```

If you wish that your props object is exactly your product object you have to change the way you set your tag... In your case, it would be something like this...

```
 const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/products")
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(resp => {
        console.log(resp); //line 55
        setProducts(resp)
      })
  }, []);

  return (
      <div>
        {products.map(product => {
          return <Product {...product} />
        })}
      </div>
  );
```